# How to best sort data from MySQL table in PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a script in PHP like this one:

```
if(isset($_GET["ord"]))
{
    switch($_GET["ord"])
    {
      case 1: $ord = "name ASC";
              break;

      case 2: $ord = "surname ASC";
              break;

      case 3: $ord = "date ASC";
              break;

      case 4: $ord = "zone ASC";
              break;

      case 5: $ord = "latency DESC";
              break;

      default: $ord = "name ASC";
               break;

    }
}
else
{
    $ord = "name ASC";
}
```

And using it in code like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT people.name AS Name, surname, date, zone, latency FROM people WHERE online=1 ORDER BY $ord");
$content->ADD('<table class="online"><tr><th><a href="?s=online&amp;ord=1">Name</a></th><th><a href="?s=online&amp;ord=2">Surname</a></th><th><a href="?s=online&amp;ord=3">Date</a></th><th><a href="?s=online&amp;ord=4">Zone</a></th><th><a href="?s=online&amp;ord=5">Latency</a></th></tr>');
while ($resss = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  $content->ADD('<tr><td align="center">'.$resss["name"].'</td>');
  $content->ADD('<td>'.$resss["surname"].'</td>');
  $content->ADD('<td>'.$resss["date"].'</td>');
  $content->ADD('<td>'.$resss["zone"].'</td>');
  $content->ADD('<td>'.$resss["latency"].'</td>');
  $content->ADD('</tr>');

}
```

It is actually working quite awsome but I have problem when I need to change ASC and DESC sorting - so my question is how to rewrite my script to also be in acs/desc sorting available in outup data? Thank you.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: OK I will try to learn this system but still do not answer my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a header row with name, something like:

```
$content->ADD('<tr><td align="center">Name</td>');
```

you could change it to be:

```
$sort_order = "name ASC";
if($ord == 'name ASC') {
    $sort_order = "name DESC";
}
$content->ADD('<tr><td align="center"><a href="?ord=$sort_order">Name</a></td>');
```

then, when your script processes the "ord" variable, it will be based off your "Name" column header. Once you get this going, you'll probably want to change your variables a bit, using something like a "?sortby=name&sortorder=ASC" request variable, but get the above working first and then you'll see it.

Comment: And I know you didn't like @robert-sim's jQuery solution but it's relatively unobtrusive and much easier IMO. I've done it via jQuery and straight PHP and request vars--it's quite a headache going the PHP-only route.

Answer (score 2):

Off the fly, I can only think of jQuery solution, if you do not mind: [jQuery DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/). Using it would eliminate the need to make calls to your database unnecessarily.

The most basic implementation would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

Comment: This is excellent... never would have thought to sort so much data client side before.  Documentation could be a bit better, but once it's up and going it works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That whole switch is somewhat unnecessary. When performing `ORDER BY`, you can specify which column to sort by its numeric place (order) in the query.

```
select `uid`, `name` from `test` order by `uid` asc
```

should give the same results as

```
select `uid`, `name` from `test` order by 1 asc
```

You could modify the code with the switch to accept the argument for `desc` / `asc`, and simply use the numeric as the `order by` target. The switch you posted has the benefit of not producing weird queries like `order by 555`, but that can be solved in other ways as well. This is just some basic information to get you started with the coding, but if you need clarification(s), drop a comment

Comment: According to me this is just another way of doing my code but still not solving sorting by asc/desc when I click on "name" in site